# Conditional evaluation of Sweave chunk

Tags: conditionals, external-files, r, sweave

I'm using some R code to import and manipulate a time series. The code takes some minutes to run and, as a result, it generates a relatively small time series.

Now, to prevent typesetting to take an annoying amount of time, I thought I could directly import the final result in R/Sweave but, at the same, I would like people that do not have the saved object to automatically generate it. Something like

```
\IfFileExists{"data.dat"}{
<<echo=FALSE>>=
##  import data ##
@

<<eval=FALSE>>=
##  code to generate data ##
@

}
{

<<>>=
##  code to generate data ##
@

<<echo=FALSE>>=
## save data in data.dat ##
@

}
```

The problem is that the Sweave compilation ignores the `\IfFileExists` and executes both chunks. Is there a way to prevent Sweave to execute chunk if a particular condition is satisfied (i.e. a file exists) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need LaTeX for this, only R:

```
if (file.exists("data.dat")==TRUE) cat("yes") else cat ("no")
```

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the workaround I came up with, but it has the drawback of showing the if in the R code, which is something I don't really like (as the if is only related to the typesetting part, it's not something relevant that should be printed in the pdf).

Comment: @Saphrosit Well, then put that part in a hided R chunk. With `knitr` options you can even deactivate the echo for selected lines only.  Citing textually: "e.g. `echo=2:3` means only echo the 2nd and 3rd expressions, and `echo=-4` means to exclude the 4th expression"